# Is this convergent sum a constant?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I got this symbolic convergent sum from $\textit{Mathematica}$:
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{k!}{(2 k)!}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{e} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Where $\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ can be found [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html)

Is this convergent sum a constant?  I'm guessing "yes," but I have never encountered this kind of sum before.

Comment: What do you mean that it is a constant? The sum does not depend on anything, hence it is a number...

Comment: @DennisGulko, exactly what I thought.  Make this an answer and I'll sign off on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the request by the OP, I'm posting this as an answer:

```
 The sum does not depend on anything, hence it is a number
```

Answer (score 2):

The LHS of the equality is a convergent series, therefore it is real number (or a constant). This means that the RHS has got to be a constant. Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{e} \sqrt{\pi }$ is a constant, then $\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ must also be a constant.

Another way to look at it is (if you know the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)), it's just realising that $\displaystyle \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is simply the error function $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ evaluated at $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{2}$ (which is part of its domain), hence a constant.